If $\models \phi \lor \psi$ then not always $\models \phi$ or $\models \psi$
Task is to give an example in propositional logic which shows that if $\models \phi \lor \psi$ then not always $\models \phi$ or $\models \psi$. How can I write it? Any help would be much appreciated.
EDIT:
So if $\models p \lor \neg p$, then it always holds for any evaluation, but $\models p$ does not hold if $p$ evaluates to false and $\models \neg p$ does not if $p$ evaluates to true? That is, point here is, that seperately they can have different evaluations, right?

$\phi = p$ and $\psi = \neg p$, where $p$ is a propositional symbol?

@DavidGao Yes, I was thinking of that example, but how to formally write it down?

What do you mean? I just wrote down the example. What kind of formality do you need?

One way to formalise David's example is to consider the free Boolean algebra on one generator $p$ as a counter-model.

@DavidGao I updated my question, so is it correct reasoning?

@MateuszStruk Yes, that's right, $p$ and $\lnot p$ both have evaluations where they're false, but $p\lor \lnot p$ is true for every evaluation.

@MateuszStruk I’m not sure what you meant by “point here is, that seperately they can have different evaluations”, but otherwise the reasoning is fine.
